# WCF Service Returning "Method Not Allowed"

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services

In the process of developing my first WCF service and when I try to use it I get "Method not Allowed" with no other explanation.

I've got my interface set up with the ServiceContract and OperationContract:

```
    [OperationContract]
    void FileUpload(UploadedFile file);
```

Along with the actual method:

```
    public void FileUpload(UploadedFile file) {};
```

To access the Service I enter http://localhost/project/myService.svc/FileUpload
but I get the "Method not Allowed" error

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Your browser is sending an HTTP GET request: Make sure you have the WebGet attribute on the operation in the contract:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IUploadService
{
    [WebGet()]
    [OperationContract]
    string TestGetMethod(); // This method takes no arguments, returns a string. Perfect for testing quickly with a browser.

    [OperationContract]
    void UploadFile(UploadedFile file); // This probably involves an HTTP POST request. Not so easy for a quick browser test.
 }
```

Comment: This didn't work for me (asp.net on framework 4.0) but darthjit's answer below did

Comment: so why is this one checked instead of darjhit's?

Comment: @LeiLeyba Because the author marks the answer, not the community

Comment: I was getting this error with `[WebGet()]`. For me I had to use `WebInvoke(Method:="GET" ...`

Answer (score 76):

If you are using the `[WebInvoke(Method="GET")]` attribute on the service method, make sure that you spell the method name as "GET" and not "Get" or "get" since it is case sensitive! I had the same error and it took me an hour to figure that one out.

Comment: This solution helped me resolve the 405 error too! Thank you!

Comment: hehe i used Get Instead of GET and I had tried many other answers from stackoverflow nothing worksout . Superb you save ma day .. Thanks for valid information

Comment: Aah! this made me go mad for a while!

Comment: Wow, glad I found this because it gave me a clue: I was getting this same error with `[WebGet()]` but after seeing this, I changed it to `WebInvoke(Method:="GET" ...` and that fixed my issue and data was returned as expected.

Comment: Helped me very much. I had this problem with 'Method = "Post"', when I replaced it with  'Method = "POST"' everything worked.

Answer (score 4):

The basic intrinsic types (e.g. `byte`, `int`, `string`, and arrays) will be serialized automatically by WCF. Custom classes, like your UploadedFile, won't be.

So, a silly question (but I have to ask it...): is UploadedFile marked as a `[DataContract]`? If not, you'll need to make sure that it is, and that each of the members in the class that you want to send are marked with [DataMember].

Unlike remoting, where marking a class with [XmlSerializable] allowed you to serialize the whole class without bothering to mark the members that you wanted serialized, WCF needs you to mark up each member. (I believe this is changing in .NET 3.5 SP1...)

A tremendous resource for WCF development is what we know in our shop as "the fish book": [Programming WCF Services](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Programming-WCF-Services-Juval-Lowy/dp/0596526997/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1220419338&sr=8-4) by Juval Lowy. Unlike some of the other WCF books around, which are a bit dry and academic, this one takes a practical approach to building WCF services and is actually useful. Thoroughly recommended.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this exact same issue today. I had installed IIS, but did not have the activate WCF Services Enabled under .net framework 4.6.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're using an incorrect address:

> To access the Service I enter http://localhost/project/myService.svc/FileUpload

Assuming you mean this is the address you give your client code then I suspect it should actually be:

```
http://localhost/project/myService.svc
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been having this same problem for over a day now - finally figured it out. Thanks to @Sameh for the hint.

Your service is probably working just fine. Testing POST messages using the address bar of a browser won't work. You need to use Fiddler to test a POST message.

Fiddler instructions...
http://www.ehow.com/how_8788176_do-post-using-fiddler.html

Comment: Also, just found the RESTClient plugin for Firefox / Chrome / others. It's a lot easier to use than Fiddler - might be a better choice to start with.

Comment: You don't *need* to use Fiddler. You can do this without installing anything; just save the following HTML to file (having edited the URL) and open it in a browser: <html><body><form action="<your url>" method="post"> <input type="text" name="data" value="test" /><input type="submit" /></form></body></html>

Answer (score 0):

Only methods with WebGet can be accessed from browser IE ; you can access other http verbs by just typing address

You can either try Restful service startup kit of codeples or use fiddler to test your other http verbs

Comment: I think you are really trying to say this: You can test GET messages in a browser but other verbs must be tested in Fiddler? I agree.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add in web.config

```
<endpoint address="customBinding" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicConfig" contract="WcfRest.IService1"/>  

<bindings>  
    <customBinding>  
        <binding name="basicConfig">  
            <binaryMessageEncoding/>  
            <httpTransport transferMode="Streamed" maxReceivedMessageSize="67108864"/>  
        </binding>  
    </customBinding>
```

Answer (score 0):

My case: configuring the service on new server.  ASP.NET 4.0 was not installed/registered properly; svc extension was not recognized.