# Issue consuming ReST WCF in MVC3

Tags: wcf, asp.net-mvc-3, rest

I have created a ReST WCF Service in .NET 4.0. It's hosted in IIS (.svc). The .svc file is mapped correctly in IIS 7.5. When I try to consume the WCF Service in MVC 3, I get an error :

> "The remote server returned an unexpected response: (405) Method Not Allowed."

I created a proxy by adding a service reference to my MVC project. Let me know if you have encountered this issue and have the solution.

Please help! I already spent 2 days on it.

Comment: See stack overflow issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41155/wcf-service-returning-method-not-allowed

Answer (score 0):

Consuming a REST service should not involve adding a service reference as in the REST style the client and service are independent.

In order to consume a rest service please see this [article](http://rajeshsv.blogspot.com/2011/11/net-client-to-invoke-rest-service.html).

Also 405 Method not allowed might be that you are trying to perform a GET operation on a method that is defined for POST or vice versa.

Comment: thanks for your help! You were right about performing a "POST" request on "GET" method. When I changed it to "POST", it worked just fine. I would like it to be "GET" method. How can I keep that and still use proxy? I went through the link, and I have a question. How do you have access "CompositeType" class. All my datacontracts are defined in a separate project. I would like to take advantage of strongly-type object in MVC3. My WCF expects JSON request and response. Thanks in advance!

Comment: In order for you to access datacontracts since they are in a seperate project you can add the reference in the MVC project and also in your WCF Service project. If any client needs to access your service you can just ship the contracts project. But make sure that the project just has only contracts and nothing else. If you would like to change the method from POST to GET you can replace the WebInvoke Attribute with WebGet and that should be enough. Else create a different method with the WebGet Attribute. If you want to use a proxy then the communication between client & service would use SOAP

Comment: Is there a way to perform GET operation on REST WCF using proxy? If yes, how? If not, what other alternatives are there?

Comment: If you try to invoke a service method via proxy it doesnt follow REST principal, and the communication would be through SOAP. Just mark your webmethod with operation contract and you can invoke it via proxy.