# WCF REST call returns "Method not allowed" exception

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, exception

I am trying to create a WCF Restful Service.

Here is my contract: (The ActivateUser class extends the BaseResult class).

```
namespace SmartShopServerContract {
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService {
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate="au/{eMail}/{password}/{idHandy}")]
    ActivateUserResult ActivateUser(string eMail, string password, string idHandy);
}

// Basisklasse der Resultate --> alle Resultate haben einen definierten Status!
[DataContract]
public abstract class BaseResult {

    private string status;

    public BaseResult(string status) {
        this.status = status;   
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string Status {
        get { return this.status; } 
    }
}

// Result für ActivateUser
[DataContract]
public class ActivateUserResult : BaseResult {
    public ActivateUserResult(string status)
        : base(status) {
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string CryptedPassword { get; set; }
}
```

}

Here is the implementation of the Service:

```
namespace SmartShopServerService {
public class ServiceSmartShop : IService {

    public ActivateUserResult ActivateUser(string eMail, string password, string idHandy) {
        return new ActivateUserResult("OK") {
            CryptedPassword="testatsa"
        };
    }
```

And there is the Web.config file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
     <standardEndpoints>
      <webHttpEndpoint>
        <standardEndpoint helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="false" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json">
        </standardEndpoint>
      </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
    <services>
      <service name="SmartShopServerService.ServiceSmartShop" behaviorConfiguration="RESTBehavior">
        <endpoint address="/" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="SmartShopServerContract.IService" behaviorConfiguration="SmartShopBehavior"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="RESTBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" policyVersion="Policy15"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="SmartShopBehavior">
          <webHttp automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.5" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>
  </startup>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="WebDAVModule"/>
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I am testing this with the "VS2012 native tool commant prompt" like this:

```
svcutil.exe http://localhost:51162/SmartShopService.svc/au/data1/data2/data3
```

The code is being executed, but I am still getting a Method not allowed (405) exception.

Any thoughts on that?

--> currently local use

--> IIS Express (Visual Studio 2012)

Comment: This question and answer might provide some insight.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/545754/1181408

Comment: How are you invoking the http operation?  i.e. show the javascript/jquery or WebClient/etc...

Comment: One way to get this error is to invoke with the wrong verb.  e.g. you've defined it for GET, if you used POST to invoke that URL then the WebAPI framework to kick back the Method Not Allowed error.

Comment: I am already using the [WebGet()] annotation. (see code above). the http operation is being invoked with the vs2012 native tool command prompt (svcutil.exe) --> code above ;). with the svcutil.exe http://localhost:51162/SmartShopService.svc/au/data1/data2/data3 command i am able to invoke the methode using GET.

Comment: It's not clear what you're doing.  svcutil is for generating client proxy code to invoke the web verbs--but you've only provided the server-side code that implements the operation.  Without knowing how that server code is being invoked, we can't tell what's wrong.  You say "I am able to invoke the method using GET", does that mean it works or not?

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding. i meant that the method is already being executed with this configuration (debugging). The problem was the DataContract structure in the SmartShopServerContract. (see answers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the base class (BaseResult) for the ActivateUser class --> BaseResult

It seems like that it is not possible to extend a DataContract class and expect it to work.

Now i am using a Interface instead of a base class

```
public interface IResult {
    string Status{get;set;}
}


[DataContract]
public class ActivateUserResult : IResult {

    [DataMember]
    public string CryptedPassword { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

This is working....thats all i know ;)

Answer (score 3):

You're using svcutil to create a proxy for a "RESTful WCF service". [This does not work](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/03/26/mixing-add-service-reference-and-wcf-web-http-a-k-a-rest-endpoint-does-not-work.aspx). The quick reason is that Web endpoints do not expose metadata for the svcutil tool to know what requests it needs to send to it. The long version is on the linked blog post.

Comment: thanks for the reply. it is true what you are saying, but this was not the problem (or at least the main problem), because with this configuration it is not working at all. But I found a solution ;)

Comment: Glad you found a solution. Can you post it as an answer and accept it so others will learn from what you've been through? Thanks!