# Consume JSON WCF services in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, wcf, web-services

I want to consume my json wcf web service from the code behind of my page:

Default.aspx.cs

```
string result = url + "/ExecuteAction?callback=?";
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(result);
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/json";
httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
{
    string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
    {
        action = "HelloWorld",
        args = "Nabila"
    });
    streamWriter.Write(json);
    streamWriter.Flush();
    streamWriter.Close();
}
var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
    var response = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

My service:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public string ExecuteAction(string action, string args)
{
    String JSONResult = String.Empty;
    MethodInfo action = services.GetMethod(action, BindingFlags.NonPublic |    BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
    JSONResult =(String)action.Invoke(null, new object[] { args });
}
```

services.cs

```
public static string HelloWorld(string msg)
{
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject("Hello World"+msg);
}
```

I get the following exception :

> consume json wcf web service from c# The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed. System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e)

Note:
It works when I consume my web service using javascript:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        crossDomain: true,
        timeout: 10000,
        url: getUrl() + "ExecuteAction?callback=?",
        data: { action: "HelloWorld", args: 'test'},
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "jsonp"
    }).done(function (msg) {alert("success");}).fail(function () {alert("error");});
```

Could you please help me.

Thanks.

Nabila.

Comment: May http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41155/wcf-service-returning-method-not-allowed will help

Comment: Please take a look at my edits

Comment: You configure your method as `WebGet` but `POST` data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am observing that your problem is with **DataType**. In your Javascript call, you are setting **datType** as **jsonp**

```
dataType: "jsonp"
```

And in your Default.aspx.cs file you are sending plain JSON. There is [difference between JSON and JSONP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887209/what-are-the-differences-between-json-and-jsonp).

Try changing JSON type in your **Deafult.aspx.cs** file and then run. This might resolve your problem.

**EDIT:**
Change your Contract as:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "json")]
public string ExecuteAction(JSONRequest request)
{
   String JSONResult = String.Empty;
   MethodInfo action = services.GetMethod(action, BindingFlags.NonPublic |    BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
   JSONResult =(String)action.Invoke(null, new object[] { args });
}

[DataContract]
public class JSONRequest
{
   [DataMember]
   public string Action {get; set;}
   [DataMember]
   public string Args {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but how do I create a jsonp object?

Comment: I have changed my contract and it is still the same error

Comment: Hmm! Change Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

Comment: No idea of js. If it works please mark it as accepted so that others can take benefit from it.