# VB.net WCF cross Domain Access to services

Tags: vb.net, wcf

I am recently started to learn WCF and I am successful only when post in the same server domain name for example if I do it from the www.example1.com I am successful but when I try call by wcf from the www.testweb.com I was getting an following errors.

Request Header:

```
OPTIONS /wcftest.svc/test HTTP/1.1
```

Here is my svc

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="VB" Debug="true" Service="test" CodeBehind="~/App_Code/test.vb"  Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebScriptServiceHostFactory"%>
```

Here is my test.vb class file

```
Imports System.ServiceModel
Imports System.ServiceModel.Activation
Imports System.ServiceModel.Web
Imports System.ServiceModel.Description

<ServiceContract(Namespace:="")>
<AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode:=AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)>
Public Class test

    <OperationContract()>
    <WebInvoke(Method:="GET", BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json)> _
    Public Function GetData(ByVal value As String) As String
        Return String.Format("wcftest - You entered: {0}", value)
    End Function

    <OperationContract()>
<WebInvoke(Method:="GET", BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json)> _
    Public Function test() As String
    //written my functions
    End Function


End Class
```

And I have trying a lot to get it to work still I am successful. So anyone could help me how to solve it I have tried a lot but I was not successful.

Comment: What is your http path? Open it in browser and write here what you see in browser.

Comment: http://www.example.com/wcfTest.svc/test

Comment: So what does the browser show you?

Comment: Is your IIS running? Are the ports open (port 80)?

Comment: yes my IIS is running, and when I inspect the elements in mypage Iwas getting like 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Comment: Does adding WebGet() help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41155/wcf-service-returning-method-not-allowed

Comment: What do you see in browser for this page: example.com/wcfTest.svc?

Comment: yes I have it. I see 
You have created a service.

To test this service, you will need to create a client and use it to call the service. You can do this using the svcutil.exe tool from the command line with the following syntax:


svcutil.exe http://www.example.eu/wcftest.svc?wsdl
You can also access the service description as a single file:

http://www.example.eu/wcftest.svc?singleWsdl