# Jquery Ajax in .Net Unexpected token <

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax, json

**I have written a function in javascript**

```
function abc()
{
   var Url = "MyService.svc/MyMethod";
   var Param = '{"Keyword":"' + Keyword + '","Type":"' + type + '"}';
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: Url,
      data: Param,
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (msg) {
         var pdResults = msg.MyServiceResult;
      },
      error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
      }
   });
}
```

//---------------------------------------------------

**on the server side I have written method**

```
public string MyMethod(string Keyword, string Type)
{
  return "1";
}
```

//---------------------------------------------------
**Problem :**

Problem is Javascript method never goes into success method.
in error method it shows

`parse error: Unexpected token <`

I don't know what part is causing this problem.
I couldn't find a solution, can somebody fix it.

Comment: The code you shared doesn't reproduce this. it's probable coming from somewhere else...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should return `"{ result: 1}"` or `"{ \"result\": 1 }"` in your `MyMethod`. Because `jQuery` trys to parse the response as a valid `JSON` string, but what you response is `1`, which is not valid.

See http://json.org for more infomation.

Comment: I have tried that it didn't work.
When I write dataType as "jsonp" it calls server side method but if I write it as "json", it doesn't call server side method.

Comment: Change the `type: "POST"` to `type: "GET"` and try again.

Comment: POST to GET...It worked...! :)
Thanx man!
But its weird POST isn't working

Comment: I think you should change your server side code, but I'm not familiar with .NET. Here is a link, maybe it could help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41155/wcf-service-returning-method-not-allowed

Answer (score 0):

I think you should monitor in **developer tools** or tools like **fiddler** that what parameters are actually being posted to the server.