# Exception : ProtocolException was unhandled by user code

Tags: c#, wcf

Please help me on below error : The exception is being thrown while consuming the service using client code

> Exception Details: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.

```
using (var customerCreditService = new CustomerCreditServiceClient())
{
     var creditLimit = customerCreditService.GetCreditLimit(customer.Firstname, 
                                   customer.Surname, customer.DateOfBirth);
            (**Exception thrown while calling this method**)
}
```

> Error Message : The remote server returned an unexpected response: (405) Method Not Allowed.
>
> Stack Trace : Server stack trace: 
>          at >System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestReplyResponse(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response, HttpChannelFactory`1 factory, WebException responseException, ChannelBinding channelBinding) at 
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]: 
>          at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
>          at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
>          at App.ICustomerCreditService.GetCreditLimit(String firstname, String surname, DateTime dateOfBirth)
>          at App.CustomerCreditServiceClient.GetCreditLimit(String firstname, String surname, DateTime dateOfBirth) in 
>       \App\CustomerCreditService.cs:line 53
>          at App.Customer.doCreditCheck(Customer customer) in 
>       \App\Customer.cs:line 36
>          at App.SilverCustomer.doCreditCheck(Customer customer) in \App\SilverCustomer.cs:line 14
>          at App.CustomerService.AddCustomer(Customer customer) in \App\App\CustomerService.cs:line 64
>          at App.Tests.CustomerUnitTests.AddCustomer_DoCreditCheck_ForSilver() in \App.Tests\CustomerUnitTests.cs:line 74

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WCF Service Returning "Method Not Allowed"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41155/wcf-service-returning-method-not-allowed)

Comment: No that's not working..  Am calling the method from TDD test environment.

Comment: You need to show more code. [mcve]